# Losing information on jquery .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am passing two jsons via post with `.load()`, but I am losing information because they are too big, I believe. Transforming them to string with `JSON.stringify`, I can retrieve the information complete, but it does not seems like the best solution.

What is the maximum amount of data that I can send via `.load()` and what would be a better option to do that?

My code is basically this:

```
$('.main_content').load("/feedback",{questions:questions,chances:chances});
```

And in this /feedback, I have a php method where I receive this methods:

```
public function feedback(Request $request){

    $questions = $request->input("questions");
    $chances = $request->input("chances");
    $values = ["questions"=>$questions,
        "chancesOfApproval"=>$chances];

    return response()->json($values);
}
```

Comment: That's likely dependent on your server. That aside, what's the code you're using that involves the `.load()` call?

Comment: I am passing 2 jsons on it. if I put them both on a txt file, the file has 94kb. I believe they are kind of big

Comment: I meant "show your code" as in: show the relevant source code and both ends of the connection. We can't really help without knowing what you're doing code-wise.